# How do I load the SAVED value 'highscore' into my MainActicity?

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

In my `Game.class` I already have a saved value for the `highscore` and when I load it in the same activity it works perfectly.

The problem here is that when I want to show the `highscore` in the `MainActivity` it shows the default value which is 0.

Then when I continue with the game and it shows it correctly because it loads the saved value ONCE I run the `Game.class Activity`.

But if I close the app and restart it, AGAIN it shows the default value 0.
How can I load the saved value and not the default value once I open the app?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView hsTxt;  //highscore View

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        hsTxt = findViewById(R.id.hs_main);

        hsTxt.setText(String.valueOf(game.highscore));
    }
}


public class game extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView hsTxt;
    TextView scTxt;

    int counter_int;  //contador tomado del textView
    String result;
    String counter_string;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);

        hsTxt = findViewById(R.id.highscoreTxt);
        scTxt = findViewById(R.id.scoreTxt);

        SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("HighScore", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        highscore = pref.getInt("HS", 0);   //HERE IS THE DEFAULT VALUE
    }

    public void TapShape(View view) {

        counter_string = counterLayout.getText().toString();
        counter_int = Integer.parseInt(counter_string);
        counter_int += 10;  //CONTADOR AUMENTA DE 10 SIEMPRE
        score = counter_int;

        result = String.valueOf(counter_int);
        counterLayout.setText(result);    //SCORE IS INCREMENTED PER TAP


        if (score > highscore) {
            highscore = score;

            //HERE I SAVED THE HIGHSCORE
            SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("HighScore", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit(); //se edita el archivo 'HighScore'
            editor.putInt("HS", highscore);
            editor.commit();

        }
    }
```

Comment: IN THE CODE I SHOW YOU FIRST THE MAIN ACTIVITY AND THEN THE GAME ACTIVITY

Comment: There are few problems and solutions to this problem, does your app start with `MainActivity`? How do you intent between activities? You can use `extra` while for between `game Activity` to `MainActivity`

Comment: yes, it starts with MainActivity then once the user press a button it goes to gameActivity

Answer (score 0):

I solved it loading the saved data this way.

```
SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("HighScore",Context.MODE_PRIVATE); //this file was previously created, I just loaded it.
 int hs = pref.getInt("HS",0);
 hsTxt.setText(String.valueOf(hs));
```